# Can't create test for JAR project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.
I've created the libs folder and have the jar files in there, but when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, no options come up to create a test?

Comment: If you want to generate the test stub, you need the source code for the class. Otherwise you just write your test class manually and call the methods of the jar you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create/open a test for a given class in IntelliJ, first open that class, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. A subwindow should open that allows you to create new a new test or to open existing ones.

Comment: When I do that it says "no test subject found"?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050488/intellij-idea-navigate-to-test-subject) is probably related, I'd give it a try.